# How to verify api response array contains value without indexing in Chai

Tags: arrays, cypress, chai

If I make an api request and the response I get back looks something like this:

```
    {
      applicationVersion: "0.0.0.0",
          healthResults: [
            {
              name: "Api1",
              responseTimeInMilliseconds: 256,
              isAvailable: true,
              customProperties: {}
            },
            {
              name: "Api2",
              responseTimeInMilliseconds: 539,
              isAvailable: false,
              customProperties: {}
            },
            {
              name: "Api3",
              responseTimeInMilliseconds: 256,
              isAvailable: true,
              customProperties: {}
            }
          ]
    }
```

In Chai (Cypress), how can I write an assertion that verifies each api with name x, has isAvailable set to true, without using an index since the healthResults array could be in a different order on a different server.  Eg, this won't work:

```
expect(response.body.healthResults[0].isAvailable).to.be.true
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous [API Test examples](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/tree/develop/cypress/tests/api) in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).  Look through the examples for uses of [Cypress Assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#BDD-Assertions) against the API responses.